# Linq get random row (one to many) and assign that to a variable/list?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a model designed as such:

```
public class SearchListing
{
    public int property_id { get; set; }
    public int office_property_id { get; set; }
    public String office_property_description { get; set; }
    public String property_name { get; set; }
    public String property_street { get; set; }
    public String property_city { get; set; }
    public String property_state { get; set; }
    public String property_zip { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> numBedrooms { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> numBathrooms { get; set; }
    public bool numGarages { get; set; }
}
```

I was to fill this model using one linq statement. This model can be used standalone or there can be a list of searchlistings. My linq statement has to be able to retrieve all properties that meet a criteria.

Properties have a one to many relationship with officeproperties. So one propriety could have multiple office specific information about that property. I want to pick ONE of those offices at random to bring in their information about the property. I have the following linq:

```
propertyIDSearch = (from p in db.Property
                    join bp in db.OfficeProperty on p.property_id equals bp.property_id 
                    join b in db.Office on bp.office_id equals b.office_id                                                                                
                    where b.status == 1 && bp.active_listing == true
                    orderby Guid.NewGuid()    
                    select new SearchListing
                    {
                        property_id = p.property_id,
                        office_property_id = bp.office_property_id,
                        office_property_description  = bp.description,
                        property_name = p.prop_name,
                        property_street = p.street,
                        property_city = p.city,
                        property_state = p.state,
                        property_zip = p.zip,
                        numBedrooms = p.bed_rooms,
                        numBathrooms = p.baths,
                        numGarages = p.garage
                    })
                   .Take(1)
                   .ToList<SearchListing>();
```

This works but only gives me one property. I was thinking of doing something like the following, but then I can not use p.property_id in the statements:

```
propertyIDSearch = (from p in db.Property
                    select new SearchListing
                    {
                        property_id = p.property_id,
                        office_property_id = (from bp in OfficeProperty
                                              join b in Office on b.office_id equals bp.office_id
                                              where p.property_id equals bp.property_id 
                                              select bp.office_property_id)
                        office_property_description = bp.description,
                        property_name = p.prop_name,
                        property_street = p.street,
                        property_city = p.city,
                        property_state = p.state,
                        property_zip = p.zip,
                        numBedrooms = p.bed_rooms,
                        numBathrooms = p.baths,
                        numGarages = p.garage
                    })
                   .ToList<SearchListing>();
```

That code does not work and was just written to show a thought process. I need to fill office property description and office property id with that one random instance of the office for that particular property. If I run the linq in the select statement like I just did, I can not use that instance to get description. If I try to add in in the join I can't use p.property id:

```
propertyIDSearch = (from p in db.Property
                    join bp in (from bp in OfficeProperty
                                join b in Office on b.office_id equals bp.office_id 
                                where p.property_id equals bp.property_id
                                select bp).ToList()[new Random().Next(list.count)] on p.property_id equals bp.property_id                                             
                    select new SearchListing
                    {
                        property_id = p.property_id,
                        office_property_id = bp.office_property_id
                        office_property_description  = bp.description,
                        property_name = p.prop_name,
                        property_street = p.street,
                        property_city = p.city,
                        property_state = p.state,
                        property_zip = p.zip,
                        numBedrooms = p.bed_rooms,
                        numBathrooms = p.baths,
                        numGarages = p.garage
                    })
                   .ToList<SearchListing>();
```

This does not work either.

**EDIT:**

I tried this based off of the suggestions provided and this seems to work. Is there anything bad with this method?

```
propertyIDSearch = (from p in db.Property
                                        join bp in db.OfficeProperty on p.property_id equals bp.property_id
                                        where bp.Officeproperty_id == (from bp2 in db.OfficeProperty
                                                                        join b in db.Office on bp2.Office_id equals b.Office_id
                                                                        where b.status == 1 && bp2.active_listing == true && bp2.property_id == p.property_id
                                                                        orderby Guid.NewGuid()
                                                                        select bp2.Office_property_id).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()
                                        //Build the where clauses based off of the search criteria
                                        where p.property_id == (searchCriteria.propertyID > 0 ? searchCriteria.propertyID : p.property_id)                                        
                                        where p.geography_id == (searchCriteria.citySelected > 0 ? searchCriteria.citySelected : p.geography_id)
                                        select new SearchListing
                                        {
                                            property_id = p.property_id,
                                            Office_property_id = bp.Office_property_id,
                                            Office_property_description = bp.description,
                                            property_name = p.prop_name,
                                            property_street = p.street,
                                            property_city = p.city,
                                            property_state = p.state,
                                            property_zip = p.zip,
                                            numBedrooms = p.bed_rooms,
                                            numBathrooms = p.baths,
                                            numGarages = p.garage
                                        }).ToList<SearchListing>();
```

Comment: i modify my code, would you mind taking a look at that?

Answer (score 1):

Hi instead of putting an office_property_id why not include a property

```
public OfficeProperty OfficeProperty;
```

on SearchListing.

and instead of joining why not use virtual property like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<OfficeProperty> OfficeProperties;
```

and for Office :

```
public Office Office;
```

on Property Class that way when you select you can do this:

```
var rand = new Random();

propertyIDSearch = (from p in db.Property.Include(op => op.OfficeProperties).Include(o => o.Office)                                                                            
                where p.Office.status == 1 && p.OfficeProperties.where(op => op.active_listing == true).Any()
                orderby Guid.NewGuid()    
                select new SearchListing
                {
                    property_id = p.property_id,
                    OfficeProperty = p.OfficeProperties[rand.Next(p.OfficeProperties.Count())] // you can get the description inside this properties...
                    property_name = p.prop_name,
                    property_street = p.street,
                    property_city = p.city,
                    property_state = p.state,
                    property_zip = p.zip,
                    numBedrooms = p.bed_rooms,
                    numBathrooms = p.baths,
                    numGarages = p.garage
                })
               .Take(1)
               .ToList<SearchListing>();
```

no need for joins..thats one of the reasons EF is created..to reduce codes..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rnd = new Random();

var idPairs = (
        from p in db.Property
        join bp in db.OfficeProperty on p.property_id equals bp.property_id
        join b in db.Office on bp.office_id equals b.office_id
        where b.status == 1 && bp.active_listing == true
        select new { p.property_id, b.office_id }
    )
        .ToLookup(x => x.property_id, x => x.office_id)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            property_id = x.Key,
            office_id = x.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, x.Count())),
        })
        .ToArray();

var idPair = idPairs.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, idPairs.Count()));
```

That should get you a single randomly selected property and a randomly selected office for that property. (Please let me know if I haven't understood your selection requirements.)

Then just do your final query like this:

```
var propertyIDSearch = (
        from p in db.Property
        join bp in db.OfficeProperty on p.property_id equals bp.property_id
        join b in db.Office on bp.office_id equals b.office_id
        where p.property_id == idPair.property_id
        where b.office_id == idPair.office_id 
        select new SearchListing
        {
            property_id = p.property_id,
            office_property_id = bp.office_property_id,
            office_property_description  = bp.description,
            property_name = p.prop_name,
            property_street = p.street,
            property_city = p.city,
            property_state = p.state,
            property_zip = p.zip,
            numBedrooms = p.bed_rooms,
            numBathrooms = p.baths,
            numGarages = p.garage
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Your first section of code with the idpairs ends with an ID pair. I would like it to select more than a single property ie I can do a search for all 500 properties and each one of those 500 properties will be stored in a SearchListing with each property having a random office that is associated with that property selected. I'm guessing it doesn't change your code much, do I just replace idPair with idPairs?

Comment: Also would two queries like that be bad for the SQL database?

Comment: It does change the code a bit. You can't do a join on an in-memory collection and a database list. You have to bring the whole DB into memory for that. The only thing you can do is play with the `Contains` extension method on in-memory collections as that works on a DB call. You would then bring in your properties and your office properties collections separately into memory and then do the join there. You'd have three calls to the DB and I don't think you can improve that without loading the whole thing into memory.

Comment: I added another statement in my edit, would you mind taking a look at that?

Answer (score 0):

i have sample code, perhaps can help you:

**1. model designed table :**

```
public class OfficeProperty
{
    public int office_property_id { get; set; }
    public int property_id { get; set; }
    public int office_id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Office
{
    public int office_id { get; set; }
    public String office_name { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public int property_id { get; set; }
    public string property_name { get; set; }
}
```

**2. view design table :**

```
public class SearchListing
{
    public int office_property_id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int property_id { get; set; }
    public string property_name { get; set; }
    public int office_id { get; set; }
    public string office_name { get; set; }
}
```

**3. sample data table :**

```
List<Property> dbProperty = new List<Property>();
Property _p;

_p = new Property();
_p.property_id = 1;
_p.property_name = "guitar";
dbProperty.Add(_p);

_p = new Property();
_p.property_id = 2;
_p.property_name = "bass";
dbProperty.Add(_p);

_p = new Property();
_p.property_id = 3;
_p.property_name = "drum";
dbProperty.Add(_p);

_p = new Property();
_p.property_id = 4;
_p.property_name = "banana";
dbProperty.Add(_p);

_p = new Property();
_p.property_id = 5;
_p.property_name = "apel";
dbProperty.Add(_p);


List<Office> dbOffice = new List<Office>();
Office _b;

_b = new Office();
_b.office_id = 1;
_b.office_name = "music";
dbOffice.Add(_b);

_b = new Office();
_b.office_id = 1;
_b.office_name = "fruit";
dbOffice.Add(_b);


List<OfficeProperty> dbOfficeProperty = new List<OfficeProperty>();
OfficeProperty _bp;

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 1;
_bp.property_id = 1;
_bp.office_id = 1;
_bp.description = "property office music";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 2;
_bp.property_id = 2;
_bp.office_id = 1;
_bp.description = "property office music";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 3;
_bp.property_id = 3;
_bp.office_id = 1;
_bp.description = "property office music";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 4;
_bp.property_id = 4;
_bp.office_id = 2;
_bp.description = "property office fruit";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 5;
_bp.property_id = 5;
_bp.office_id = 2;
_bp.description = "property office fruit";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);
```

**4. LinQ :**

```
List<SearchListing> propertyIDSearch  = 
    (from bp in dbOfficeProperty
    join p in dbProperty on bp.property_id equals p.property_id
    join b in dbOffice on bp.office_id equals b.office_id
    select new SearchListing
    {
        office_property_id = bp.office_property_id,
        description = bp.description,
        property_id = p.property_id,
        property_name = p.property_name,
        office_id = b.office_id,
        office_name = b.office_name
    }).OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).ToList<SearchListing>();
```

**5. Result :**

```
-- 1 record random
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
office_property_id | description            | property_id | property_name | office_id | office_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1           | property office music  |      1      |    guitar     |     1     |  music
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- all record (5)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
office_property_id | description            | property_id | property_name | office_id | office_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1           | property office music  |      1      |    guitar     |     1     |  music
       2           | property office music  |      2      |    bass       |     1     |  music
       3           | property office music  |      3      |    drum       |     1     |  music
       4           | property office fruit  |      4      |    banana     |     2     |  fruit
       5           | property office fruit  |      5      |    apel       |     2     |  fruit
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**UPDATE : 05 Dec**

---

i modify my sample code, perhaps can help you:

**1. model designed table :**

```
public class OfficeProperty
{
    public int office_property_id { get; set; }
    public int property_id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public int property_id { get; set; }
    public string property_name { get; set; }
}
```

**2. view design table :**

```
public class SearchListing1
{
    public int property_id { get; set; }
    public string property_name { get; set; }
    public int office_property_id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class GroupOfficeProperty
{
    public int property_id { get; set; }
    public int office_property_id { get; set; } 
}
```

**3. sample data table :**

```
List<Property> dbProperty = new List<Property>();
Property _p;

_p = new Property();
_p.property_id = 1;
_p.property_name = "guitar";
dbProperty.Add(_p);

_p = new Property();
_p.property_id = 2;
_p.property_name = "banana";
dbProperty.Add(_p);


List<OfficeProperty> dbOfficeProperty = new List<OfficeProperty>();
OfficeProperty _bp;

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 1;
_bp.property_id = 1;
_bp.description = "property office music";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 2;
_bp.property_id = 1;
_bp.description = "property office electronic";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 3;
_bp.property_id = 2;
_bp.description = "property office fruit";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 4;
_bp.property_id = 2;
_bp.description = "property office food";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);`enter code here`

_bp = new OfficeProperty();
_bp.office_property_id = 5;
_bp.property_id = 2;
_bp.description = "property office plan";
dbOfficeProperty.Add(_bp);
```

**4. LinQ :**

```
List<SearchListing1> propertyIDSearch =
    dbProperty
    .Select(p => new SearchListing1
        {
            property_id = p.property_id,
            property_name = p.property_name,
            office_property_id =
                dbOfficeProperty
                .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Where(bp => bp.property_id == p.property_id)
                .Take(1)
                .FirstOrDefault().office_property_id
        })
    .Join(dbOfficeProperty, a1 => a1.office_property_id, a2 => a2.office_property_id,
        (a1, a2) => new SearchListing1
        {
            property_id = a1.property_id,
            property_name = a1.property_name,
            office_property_id = a1.office_property_id,
            description = a2.description
        })
    .ToList<SearchListing1>();
```

**5. Result :**

```
-- 2 record with 2 property and 2 office property random
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
property_id |   property_name    | office_property_id |         description
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1      |     guitar         |         2          |  property office electronic
     2      |     banana         |         5          |  property office plan
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**5. Description :**

```
-- get all property
    dbProperty
    .Select(p => new SearchListing1
        {
            property_id = p.property_id,
            property_name = p.property_name,
        })

-- get office property with random record, filter by property id, 1 row and 1 field 
    string n = 
        dbOfficeProperty
        .OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())
        .Where(bp => bp.property_id == 1)
        .Take(1)
        .FirstOrDefault().office_property_id.ToString();
```

or maybe you can change your code :

```
office_property_id = (from bp in OfficeProperty
                      join b in Office on b.office_id equals bp.office_id
                      where p.property_id equals bp.property_id 
                      select bp.office_property_id)
```

change to :

```
office_property_id = (from bp in OfficeProperty
                      join b in Office on b.office_id equals bp.office_id
                      where p.property_id equals bp.property_id 
                      orderby Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault().office_property_id
```

Comment: That is close to what I am trying to do. That works fine for one property but I need a list of a bunch of properties with a random association to one broker office that is attached to that property. So in your example with your five office ids of one through five, I could have two properties one with an officeproperty 1 and 2 and the second property with 3,4,5. The search listing that would come back would be property 1 with either officeproperty 1 or 2 select (this is the random one) and property 2 with either 3,4,5 selected.

Comment: I added another statement in my edit, would you mind taking a look at that?

Comment: I'm a little confushed at the ".Join(dbOfficeProperty, a1 => a1.office_property_id, a2 => a2.office_property_id,
        (a1, a2) => new SearchListing1" part, like what is it doing? What is a1, a2, and (a1,a2)? I'm not used to seeing linq with the .select and stuff, I'm used to seeing it the way I wrote it. Don't suppose you can write the same thing using that?